# How do I redirect a controller to a particular vocabulary overview?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, redirection

I want to redirect my controller to a specific vocabulary page.
I redirect my controller using this code.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

public function importTypes() {
  $liste_types = $this->getListTypes();

    $batch = [
      'title' => t('Importation des types'),
      'operations' => [],
      'finished' => '\Drupal\zotero\Controller\ZoteroController::importOver',
    ];

    foreach ($liste_types as $type) {
      $batch['operations'][] = ['\Drupal\zotero\Controller\ZoteroController::create_term_from_zotero',[$type['localized']]];
    }

    batch_set($batch);
    return batch_process(\Url::fromInternalUri('admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/my_voca_id/overview'));
}
```

It throws this error.

> Error: Class 'Url' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to access a method of the `\Url` class, but that class doesn't exist. The class you are trying to use is `\Drupal\Core\Url`, which is different from the `\Url` class. (Different namespace means different class.)
As you already added the `use Drupal\Core\Url;` line in your code, you just reference that class as in `Url::fromInternalUri()` (without `\`).

In your case, since you are already using an internal path, the last two lines of the code you are showing could simply be the following ones.

```
batch_set($batch);
return batch_process('admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/my_voca_id/overview');
```

In fact, [`batch_process()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/batch_process/8.3.x) accepts two kinds of values, for the first parameter:

- A path
- A [`Url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.3.x) object

As example of call to `batch_process()` and redirect, see [`LocaleController::checkTranslation()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21src%21Controller%21LocaleController.php/function/LocaleController%3A%3AcheckTranslation/8.3.x), which a method of a controller defined from a module.

```
  $this->moduleHandler()->loadInclude('locale', 'inc', 'locale.compare');

  // Check translation status of all translatable project in all languages.
  // First we clear the cached list of projects. Although not strictly
  // necessary, this is helpful in case the project list is out of sync.
  locale_translation_flush_projects();
  locale_translation_check_projects();

  // Execute a batch if required. A batch is only used when remote files
  // are checked.
  if (batch_get()) {
    return batch_process('admin/reports/translations');
  }

  return $this->redirect('locale.translate_status');
```

Inside [locale.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.routing.yml/8.3.x), you will notice that the path associated to the *locale.translate_status* route is */admin/reports/translations*, the path passed to `batch_process()` in the code I am showing.

```
locale.translate_status:
  path: '/admin/reports/translations'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\locale\Form\TranslationStatusForm'
    _title: 'Available translation updates'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'translate interface'
```

Notice that, if you are calling `batch_process()`, you don't need to execute the redirect with the `redirect()` method of the controller. As you see in the code used from the Drupal core module, the call to `$this->redirect()` is necessary only if there isn't any batch to execute.
In your case, as you are adding the batch to execute in your controller method, the same method that calls `batch_process()`, checking the value returned from `batch_get()` is not necessary.